# How to trigger action with changing inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way in javascript or jquery where i can change my div text after input was changed?

```
        <div class="expression box">
        <div class="form-field"><input class="input" id="fn" oninput="validFirstNumber(parseInt(this.value))" type="text" size="40"></div>
        <div class="form-field">+</div>
        <div class="form-field"><input class="input" id="sn" oninput="validSecondNumber(parseInt(this.value))" type="text" size="40"></div>
        <div class="form-field">=</div>
        <div class="form-field"><div id="result">?</div></div>
        </div>
```

So i need to change div with result id after fn or sn become integer.

```
function validFirstNumber(number) {


 if (6 > number || number > 9) {
        document.getElementById('fn').style.color = 'Red';
    }
    calculate();
}

function validSecondNumber(number) {
    if (6 > number || number > 9) {
        document.getElementById('sn').style.color = 'Red';
    }
    calculate();
}

function calculate() {
    if (Number.isInteger(document.getElementById('fn')) && Number.isInteger((document.getElementById('sn')))) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('fn') + document.getElementById('sn');
    }
}
```

I want to do it without buttons, action should trigger after i change numbers in inputs.

Comment: You need to add event handlers on the inputs. Look at jquery docs for `.on()` - especially, `change, input`

Comment: Maybe read the docs? https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: ok, thanks, i used .change() for calculate functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on()` method for `change` event on both input elements and update the result div with calculated result.
You  would write something like this;

```
$("#fn, #sn").on("change", function(event){
  // assuming your calculate() method is working correctly, you can call it here which updates the result div when either of inputs change 
  calculate();
  // otherwise you can write code which gets value from both input fields and update the "result" div
});
```

I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: yep, i did it something like that
var calc = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    function calculate() {
        $('input').change(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $fv = $('#fn').val();
            $sn = $('#sn').val();
            if ($.isNumeric($fv) && $.isNumeric($sn)) {
                sum = Number($fv) + Number($sn);
                $('#result').html(sum);
            }
        })
    }
    calc = calculate();
});